# Lighthouse change field value based on other property value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-lighthouse

I am using [Lighthouse](https://lighthouse-php.com/) with Laravel 5.8 to expose certain information.

Let's say I have 2 tables:

```
Order
--------
id
status


Results
--------
id
result_value
order_id
```

And my schema

```
type Order {
  id: ID!
  status: String,
  results: [Result!]! @hasMany
}

type Result {
  id: ID!
  result_value: String,
  order_id: Order! @belongsTo
}

type Query {
   order(id: ID @eq): Order @find,
}
```

If I run the next query works as expected but...

```
{
  order(id: 123) {
    status
    results {
      result_value
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is return the `order.results.result_value` as null or empty when the `order.status` is equal to something.

I'm trying to use a [custom field directive](https://lighthouse-php.com/5.1/security/authorization.html#custom-field-restrictions) but I'm not sure if what I want it's achievable since the model isn't loaded yet

Ideally a custom directive would be ideal, since this is not the only attribute and not the only relation I need to hide.

I (think I) can't use `@can` as my requests are going to use custom authentication and the data is not available through a role-based access model.

`@where`, `@whereConditions` and other filter directives cannot be used, since I'm not trying to filter all the data. I want to hide a model attributes value when another model attribute equals to a certain value

Any suggestions on how I can approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I see multiple solutions for this.

- `@method` directive on `Order`

```
type Order {
  id: ID!
  status: String,
  results: [Result!]! @method(name: "getResults") @with(relation: "results")
}
```

Then on your `Order` class handle the filtering in the `getResults` method, some like this

```php
public function getResults()
    {
        return $this->results->when($this->status === 'something', function (Collection $results) {
            return $results->each(function (Result $result) {
                $result->result_value = null;
            });
        });
    }
```

- `@method` directive on `Result`

```
type Order {
  id: ID!
  status: String,
  results: [Result!]! @hasMany
}

type Result {
  id: ID!
  result_value: String @method(name: "getResult") @with(relation: "order")
  order_id: Order! @belongsTo
}
```

And then in your `Result` model do the filtering, prob. something like

```php
    public function getResult()
    {
        if ($this->order->status === 'something') {
            return null;
        }
        
        return $this->result_value;
    }
```

This could of course also be done by using a attribute getter instead if prefered :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot everything about the question. Thanks a lot for your answer @oliver-nybroe. In the end I found an implement a more complex solution, a custom field directive. But the options you propose are by far more simple and even more efficient. I will check my solution to see if I can reimplement one of your suggestions. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. From a custom field resolver (simple but you will have to deal with pagination), to use `@builder` and to filter in someway depending on your `status`.

Comment: If I'm correct, `@builder` it's going to filter the results depending on the status. I don't want to hide the results, I want to transform 1 property and change the output without changing the actual value stored in the database. The custom field resolver is what I'm trying to do, but I'm not a fan of iterate over the previous resolver and validate the value when is a nested relation